# Are there browsers that don't support maxlength?

Tags: html, webforms, maxlength

I have a contest entry page on my company's website. In order to enter the contest, you create a login, which is just an email and a 4-digit pin. Here's the PIN field:

```
<input type="password" name="contest_pin" id="contest_pin" maxlength="4" />
```

When users submit the form, the account is created in our database, and then they get an email (which I'm copied on) that contains the email address and PIN they created.

Here's the issue: in every browser I've tested (Safari/Chrome/Firefox on Mac, Chrome/Firefox on Linux, IE7/8/9 on Windows) I CANNOT enter more than 4 digits into that PIN field. And yet, several of the emails I've received show that the user has created a pin with more than 4 characters.

How is this possible? Are there browsers that don't support maxlength? I haven't tested in Opera, or on any of the mobile browsers. It's not a huge deal if their pin is longer than 4 digits; the database will accept more. I'm just wondering how they managed to get around maxlength.

**EDITED TO ADD**

There are too many answers basically saying the same thing for me to respond individually to all of them. I KNOW that I should always do server-side validation for anything important, and we do have PHP code in place sanitizing our data, and if it was hugely important I would also have PHP code enforcing the 4-digit limit. It's not that important to us that they be only 4 characters, so I haven't enforced it. I'm just wondering why the maxlength property is not doing what it's designed to do, which is prevent users from entering more than a certain number of characters. For those of you that suggested malicious scripts or Firebug, I can be 100% certain this is not the case. Only registered users of our site (which is limited to a very specific corporate membership list) can even get to the contest entry page, and I can guarantee that none of the approximately 100 people on that list are going to be deliberately trying to circumvent an input type property.

Comment: Exactly the same question I have here, I know that max-length is easy to circumvent, but what about users who are not trying to get past any barriers.  The only thing I can think of is what Chris said, and that is that on some browsers when copying and pasting it does not work.  Just one example is IE where if you have the attribute maxlength on the text area then you can paste text inside which exceeds the maxlength.. that is not the case with inputs.. But maybe on some other browser.. I don't know why people would be pasting in pins..  Let me know if you figure out how it happened.

Comment: maxlength="x" does not work on MAC (chrome & firefox tried) when you have the type="number" attribute added :)

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius, that's because you need to use `max` and `min` or `range` attributes for `type=number`.

Comment: This is a great question. We have an internal site (so no bots or malicious users to circumvent `maxlength`) where I need maxlength to work for convenience. For example, one particular database field is set to a max length of 100 (i.e. character varying (100)). So `maxlength=100` is set on the input element. **However**, sometimes the input element allows *103* or *101* characters to slip by and the backend throws an exception. This is annoyance. I'd like to know why the input length is allowed to exceed the max length by a few extra characters sometimes; seems like a bug.

Comment: I just figured out my problem with INPUT elements allowing slightly more than `maxlength` on the database backend. The [maxlength attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) **"specifies the maximum number of characters (in Unicode code points)"**. So, for example, if a single two-byte Unicode code point—such as a multiplication sign (\u00D7)—was entered, it would count as 1 with regard to the input's maxlength, but 2 with regard to the database character length (assuming SQL_ASCII encoding).

Comment: It's 2019, this is an old thread. But it still appears, MACOS does not respect max length. I've tested this with Safari, FireFox, and Chrome. BUT on a windows machine, I am not able to enter more then x character length, this tested with FireFox and Internet Explorer. Weird eh?

Answer (score 17):

They very likely are bots that read field names and create GET and POST requests based on those rather than using the HTML form like a normal human user would.

This is why client-side validation of form is never enough to ensure data is correct. Client-side validation is nice as it's responsive for end users, but it's not able to prevent bad data from arriving at your server's doorstep.

As an example, let's say I have an input field in a form whose action is GET. My input field's maxlength is 4. When I press submit, I see the URL ending with `?field=1234`. There's nothing stopping me from updating that URL to `?field=123456789` and pressing enter. Similar things can be done with POST actions, but a tool is needed to do it.

Comment: Also using tools like firebug, I could edit the html of the site to remove the maxlength.

Comment: Not only bots, I believe in older browsers it was possible to paste longer text to bypass maxlength attribute.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that every browser supports it, here's a few links for reference :

[Maxlength | SitePointReference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/maxlength)

[Maxlength | W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp)

Obviously there are way around this - you should ensure you **ALWAYS** have adequate server-side validation, as client-side usually isn't enough on it's own.

Comment: Just a note: w3schools is generally considered a sub-par resource for programming/web development related information. It's always a good idea to verify that information elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

All browsers support maxlength. However, this attribute can easily be removed/changed using DOM methods or, for example, with Firefox's Web Developer Toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

> several of the emails I've received show that the user has created a pin with more than 4 characters.
>
> How is this possible? Are there browsers that don't support maxlength?

I would investigate the USER_AGENT and REFERER headers related to those user activities. Perhaps a malicious user submitted forms programmatically circumventing the browser restrictions, just to check your perimeter defense. If so you should see some patterns there.

Anyway these educated guesses aside, `maxlength` should not be treated as a means of securing the input. Anything client-side is not under your control, it exists merely to make user interface more intuitive, interactive. You should always check everything on the server. In that case, the PIN being composed of 4 digits, otherwise reject the input. The golden rule is to treat all user input as hostile and thoroughly validate it on the server.

Answer (score 3):

In general, trying to enforce rules for user input done client-side is a bad idea. I had an experience where we had contracted out some work to some programmers and their idea of sanitizing user input was making it so that users couldn't input more than 10 characters in any given field. A quick firebug change and, oh look, I can drop the server's database with some minimal SQL injection.

If I were you I'd check maximum lengths with whatever script adds user information to your database and return form validation errors if the user input exceeds the maximum specified length.

Answer (score 1):

This is the type of thing that you should still validate server side, even though the clients will almost always support it.  It is very easy to get around a maxlength -- Firefox Developer toolbar includes an option to "Remove Maximum Lengths", or a request can very easily be hand-edited.  I almost think that in the past you could get around a maxlength in one of the browsers simply by using cut and paste(eg, the browser wouldn't let you type more characters, but if you pasted a value that was 5+ characters it would enter them all), though I can't remember specifically which browser I saw that on...