# How to manipulate clipboard data using jquery in chrome, IE 8&9?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> This is my jquery code that I am using to truncate the pasted text, so that it doesn't exceed the maxlength of an element. The default behaviour on Chrome is to check this automatically but in IE 8 and 9 it pastes the whole text and doesn't check the maxLength of an element. Please help me to do this. This is my first time asking a question here, so please let me know if I need to provide some more details. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//var lenGlobal;
var maxLength;
function doKeypress(control) {
            maxLength = control.attributes["maxLength"].value;
            value = control.value;
            if (maxLength && value.length > maxLength - 1) {
                event.returnValue = false;
                maxLength = parseInt(maxLength);
            }
        }

//function doBeforePaste(control) {
            //maxLength = control.attributes["maxLength"].value;
            //if (maxLength) {
               // event.returnValue = false;
                //var v = control.value;
                //lenGlobal = v.length;
           // }
       // }     

  $(document).on("focus","input[type=text],textarea",function(e){

    var t = e.target;
    maxLength = parseInt($(this).attr('maxLength'));
    if(!$(t).data("EventListenerSet")){
        //get length of field before paste
        var keyup = function(){
            $(this).data("lastLength",$(this).val().length);
        };
        $(t).data("lastLength", $(t).val().length);
        //catch paste event
        var paste = function(){
            $(this).data("paste",1);//Opera 11.11+  
        };
        //process modified data, if paste occured
        var func = function(){
            if($(this).data("paste")){
                var dat = this.value.substr($(this).data("lastLength"));
                //alert(this.value.substr($(this).data("lastLength")));
               // alert(dat.substr(0,4));
                $(this).data("paste",0);
                //this.value = this.value.substr(0,$(this).data("lastLength"));
                $(t).data("lastLength", $(t).val().length); 
            if (dat == ""){
                this.value = $(t).val();
                }
                else
                {
                this.value = dat.substr(0,maxLength);
                }
            }
        };

        if(window.addEventListener) {
        t.addEventListener('keyup', keyup, false);
        t.addEventListener('paste', paste, false);
        t.addEventListener('input', func, false);    
        } else{//IE
        t.attachEvent('onkeyup', function() {keyup.call(t);});
        t.attachEvent('onpaste', function() {paste.call(t);});
        t.attachEvent('onpropertychange', function() {func.call(t);});  
        }
        $(t).data("EventListenerSet",1);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, mind you this was done in YUI but something simlar can be done for jquery. All you need to do is get the length of the comment that was entered and then truncate the text down the the desired length which in the case of this example is 2000 characters.

```
comment_text_box.on('valuechange', function(e) {
    //Get the comment the user input
    var comment_text = e.currentTarget.get('value');

    //Get the comment length
    var comment_length = comment_text.length;

    if(comment_length > 2000){
        alert('The comment entered is ' + comment_length + ' characters long and will be truncated to 2000 characters.');

        //Truncate the comment
        var new_comment = comment_text.substring(0, 2000);

        //Set the value of the textarea to truncated comment
        e.currentTarget.set('value', new_comment);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're putting too much effort into something that is apparently a browser quirk and is mostly beyond your control and could change in the future.  In fact, I can't recreate this in IE10 - it behaves just like Chrome for me.

Make sure you are validating the length on the server-side, since it's still possible to get around a field's maxlength when submitting the form input to the server (see [this somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600096/are-there-browsers-that-dont-support-maxlength)).  That's not to say you shouldn't have some client-side logic to validate the length of the input to enforce the maxlength constraint - I just think you don't need to go to the length you are attempting here to essentially intercept a paste command.  Keep it simple - having a basic length validation check in your JavaScript is going to be a lot less messy than what you have here.

Perhaps consider a bit of jQuery like this:

```
$("#myTextControl").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > $(this).attr('maxlength')) {
        DisplayLengthError();
    }
});
```

(where DisplayLengthError() is an arbitrary function that triggers some kind of feedback to the user that they have exceeded the maxlength constraint of the field, be it an error label, and alert box, etc.)

Comment: If there are users on the website using IE 8 or IE 9 then a fix may be needed even if it is a "Quirk" from an older browser. It is never good advice to ignore older browsers when you don't know what the user base has installed.

Comment: @JoeW I'm not suggesting to ignore older browsers.  Instead, I'm suggesting to have client-side validation written to check the text length, to complement the maxlength field constraint.  That should (mostly) catch any older browsers that behave like this.  Again, someone can still manipulate the data that is sent to the server from the form and bypass the maximum length of the field, regardless of whether the OP does the above "pasted input" check or not.  Server-side validation is an absolute must here too.

Comment: Depending on the limit allowed and the size of the text pasted in that may not be a good solution to the problem and I have seen what the OP is asking done before (just don't have the code that did it right now)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I have been able to truncate the length of the pasted data to match the 'maxlength' attribute of the element with an onchange event, so what's happening is user pastes data into the field and when user leaves the field, it truncates the data to only show the allowed length. Now, I am trying to figure out, if there's a way to not show the initial data into the field and only show the truncated data.

Comment: @JoeW See my edited answer with a code sample of what I was thinking of.  It would immediately let the user know that they have exceeded the maximum length designed for the input field in question.  Again, server-side validation still needs to be implemented too, but my suggested code can take the place of what the OP was trying to do.