# Text input of maxlength '30' submitting an input of '31'

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel

I currently have a form set up via Laravel with a `text` form input set up with a maxlength of 30:

```
{{ Form::text('employer' , Input::old('employer'), array('class'=>'form-control', 'maxlength'=>'30')) }}
```

I also have the column in MySQL set with a length of 30.

I just recently received an error that a submission had an input of that field that was 31 characters long, and I'm not sure how that would happen.

```
SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'employer' at row 1 (SQL:update...)
```

I assume that something is counting in array numbering with 0 being the 1st, and 29 being 30th, but I've checked in several different browsers and a maxlength of 30 has always come out as 30.

Is it possible that the `maxlength` tag is viewed differently between browsers?

I suppose I could go in and set the maxlength in my inputs to 1 below the length that it is in MySQL, but that seems to be a little messy in having different values through the application.

Comment: Is it possible that the user just removed the maxlength attribute on the client side and then just submitted a string of their own choosing?

Comment: Perhaps they went around the attribute like @MartinBean mentioned, next to front-end validation you could add validation in your Controller (or wherever you process this). Look up Validation on the laravel website (since you didn't mention the version I won't link just any), it will add an extra serverside layer, which can also return errrors/feedback.

Comment: The text input doesn't seem to be anything unusual: `Georgia Piedmont Technical Coll` So it is already being truncated, but is just an additional character over-length...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this could have happened, is because the input field maxlength attribute counts the number of characters in Unicode points. I can't directly detect any in your string, though, but it is still a way people could get around it unintentionally. As mentioned in the comments by @MartinBean, it could of course also be bypassed intentionally.

From MDN:

> maxlength
>   If the value of the type attribute is text, email, search, password, tel, or url, this attribute specifies the maximum number of characters (in Unicode code points) that the user can enter; for other control types, it is ignored. It can exceed the value of the size attribute. If it is not specified, the user can enter an unlimited number of characters. Specifying a negative number results in the default behavior; that is, the user can enter an unlimited number of characters. The constraint is evaluated only when the value of the attribute has been changed.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

And see the comments and answers on this post: [Are there browsers that don't support maxlength?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600096/are-there-browsers-that-dont-support-maxlength)

I would advise to always add serverside validation too. In Laravel this can be implemented quite easily.

For Laravel 5.1: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation

For Laravel 4.2: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation

Something pseudo-like (4.2 example, since I think you use 4.* because of the Input::old()):

```
$rules  = array(
    'employer'      => 'size:30',
);

// or \Input::all() depending on your namespacing, 
// instead of ::only(..) you can use ::all(), ::except(..)
// too, of course.
$input  = Input::only('employer'); 

$validator = Validator::make(
    $input,
    $rules
);

if ($validator->fails())
{
   // Throw whatever (preferably a custom validator exception)
   // exception you like, or return Redirect::to('form')->withInput();
   // I think if you want to use Redirect::back
   // input you have to Input::flash() first, not sure.
   throw new Exception('Validation failed.');
}

... go on then
```

I see you are using Input::old() already in your form, so perhaps you already use some kind of validation. Takes only a few minutes to implement and there really isn't a reason not to have server-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you have to validate the length of the string that it's inserted by the user. If it's you should notify the user with some red flag on the input or something like that.
In this way you should not continue the submit of the form.

Nonetheless, in the server, you have to check again for the length and decide what to do:
- save in the database with the string only with 30 characters
- not save in the database and display the error to the user coming from the server